# How can I get the inverse matrix of pretrained VGG16 weights?

Tags: tensorflow

Currently I'm trying to build a Convolutional Autoencoder based on pretrained vgg16 or vgg19. I'm wondering how I get the inverse matrix of the weights..

Comment: Share some attempt. You need to give something to community if you wanna quick answer. I can't just say i need something... I will support you Q if you post most important part of code related for your problem...

Comment: thx for your help! next time I will upload the code

Comment: It still look very pure. And more fact to make understanding better...

Comment: xaxa, sorry for that. I was just trying to extract the weights from the pre-trained keras VGG16 model. And then compute the reverse matrix of the weights

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out.. :) hope it's helpful for others. Below is the code:

```
weights = model.get_weights()

needed_weight = weights[index_number]
```

Weights will return a list of all weights in the neural network, then select the one you're looking for.

that's all.